# Convergence in $L^{1}$ of martingale

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, martingales

I have problems with the following task:
Let $X_{n} $ for $n=1,2,3...$ be independent random variables with distribution $B(n,\frac{1}{n})$ and define $Y_n=X_1...X_n$. Is $Y_n$ convergent in $L^1$?

My attempts:
I know that $Y_n$ is martingale. I tried to show that $Y_n$ are uniformly integrable but I'm not even sure if it is true. Thank you for some help.

Comment: Does it help if I tell you that $Y_n$ is a positive martingale?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to use it. I can only deduce that $Y_n$ converges a.s.

Comment: That is good. Can you guess where it converges?

Comment: I have no idea how to start guessing...

Comment: $Y_n$ is a product of integers and if at least one is...if you don't know how to continue I will tell you.

Comment: If $Y_n=0$, then for all $m>n$ we have $Y_m=0$ but... I would be thankful for the next step.:(

Comment: You need actually to prove that $Y=\lim_n Y_n=0$ a.s.. Once you did that the exercise is done. Indeed $E|Y_n-Y|=E Y_n=1$ that does not converges to 0. You can also say that by convergence theorems (equivalence) of martingales

Comment: Next step: $Y_n\to0$ iff $X_k=0$ for some $k$. What is the asymptotics of $P(X_k=0)$ when $k\to\infty$?